# How to read drupal reports programmatically?

Tags: log-messages

**Background:** I have installed [Maillog](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) and need to read its mails for my behat tests. But I can not find any functions that give me an 'easy' access to this mails via php.

**Question:** Is it possible to read Drupals reports programmatically without read data direct from database?

Comment: "Reports" as in Watchdog logs? If so, then you can use `drush watchdog-list` (`drush wd-list`) or `drush watchdog-show` (`drush ws`) for that. To show 50 latest log messages: `drush ws --count=50`

Comment: I need it in PHP without drush. I was looking for a function that filters me watchdog reports. But I figured out that I do not need it for Maillog. I just use its `maillog_maillog_load($idmaillog)` function to get the mail I need for behat. Thanks anyway for this idea.